# Can I input from and output to the same textbox is javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, output

I have been trying different options for this but as a JS beginner, I'm missing something that I can't find in the literature, so your help is appreciated.

I would like to have only two text output/input boxes on display. When the focus is on one, it accepts input and the other field becomes output for the result. If I change focus to the other box, it now allows input and the other box displays the converted result.

Initial state:

```
<label for="">Fahrenheit: </label><input type="textbox" name="far"></input><br>
<label for="">Celsius: </label><input type="textbox" name="cel"></input><br>
```

Focus on Fahrenheit turns the state to:

```
<label for="">Fahrenheit: </label><input type="textbox" name="far"></input><br>
<label for="output">Celsius: </label><input type="textbox" name="cel"></input><br>
```

Focus on Celsius turns the state to:

```
<label for="output">Fahrenheit: </label><input type="textbox" name="far"></input><br>
<label for="">Celsius: </label><input type="textbox" name="cel"></input><br>
```

Is it possible to do this so regardless of which field is getting input, the other will show the output of the converted result?
If not, what is the closest way to do what I'd like to do?

Comment: When one input field gets focussed, store the reference to the _other_ one into a variable - and then use that variable to set the output value into the corresponding field …?

Comment: A couple of HTML mistakes you have: The `<input>` element does not get a closing tag (`</input>` is not a valid HTML tag). And, the `<label>` element must either have its `for` attribute set to the `id` of the form field it's a label "for" or that form field must be a child of the `<label>` element, in which case, no `for` attribute is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline below:

```js
// Put references to the two temp fields in an array:
let tempFields = [document.getElementById("f"), document.getElementById("c")];

// Used later to store reference to inputs
let input = null;
let output = null;

// Set up one event handler on a common acnestor
// of the two input elements that trigger events
document.querySelector(".temps").addEventListener("input", function(event){
  // Determine which element triggered the event
  input = event.target;
  
  // Set output to 0 if input is index 1 in the array or
  // 1 if input index is 0 in the array
  output = tempFields.indexOf(input) === 0 ? tempFields[1] : tempFields[0];
  
  // Produce the right output
  if(output.id === "c"){ 
    output.value = (+input.value - 32) * 5/9;
  } else {
    output.value = (+input.value * 9/5) + 32;  
  }
  
});
```

```css
label { display:inline-block; width:100px; }
```

```html
<div class="temps">
  <label for="f">Fahrenheit: </label><input id="f"><br>
  <label for="c">Celsius: </label><input id="c"><br>
</div>
```